# How to start XTerm with prompt at the bottom?

Tags: bash, terminal, xterm

When starting XTerm the prompt starts at the first line of the terminal. When running commands the prompt moves down until it reaches the bottom, and from then on it stays there (not even <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Page Down</kbd> or the mouse can change this). Rather than have the start of the terminal lifetime be "special" **the prompt should always be at the bottom of the terminal.** Please note that I have a [multi-line prompt](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/9b0e5cc5d8e83abc0f381ca37ce69accf96dc86d/.bashrc#L48-L136).

Of course, it should otherwise work as before (resizeable, scrollable, no unnecessary newlines in the output, and no output mysteriously disappearing), so `PROMPT_COMMAND='echo;echo;...'` or similar is not an option. The solution ideally should not be shell-specific.

**Edit:** The [current solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153121/3645), while working in simple cases, has a few issues:

- It's **Bash specific**. An ideal solution should be portable to other shells.
- It **fails if other processes modify `PS1`**. One example is virtualenv, which adds `(virtualenv)` at the *start* of `PS1`, which then always disappears just above the fold.
- **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> now *removes* the last page of history.**

Is there a way to avoid these issues, short of forking XTerm?

Comment: Somehow, we need to introduce blank characters in Xterm's scrollbar buffer.

Comment: Actually, the prompt can be easily moved back to the top at any time by executing ```clear``` command.

Comment: @SHW I was hoping there was a setting for this rather than a hack. Terminal hacks have a tendency to introduce very subtle bugs in my experience.

Comment: @werediver But I **never** want it to be on top.

Comment: Since only the shell knows when it outputs a prompt, any solution must be in the context of the shell. Even forking XTerm won't help because XTerm doesn't know whether what it is asked to output is a prompt or not. For the terminal, the shell prompt is just another character sequence, no different from any other character sequence it might receive.

Comment: modify its init command in its terminfo file. or else, and probably easier, wrap its init in some script that can read avail lines and print them, *then* start your shell. not sure how `tput` is `bash` specific, though - it is POSIX.

Comment: Note that I've now added another option that doesn't rely on changing the `PS1` variable and therefore is immune against processes changing `PS1` (but of course processes can interfere also with this mechanism). It still is bash-specific, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If using `bash`, the following should do the trick:

```
TOLASTLINE=$(tput cup "$LINES")
PS1="\[$TOLASTLINE\]$PS1"
```

Or (less efficient as it runs one `tput` command before each prompt, but works after the terminal window has been resized):

```
PS1='\[$(tput cup "$LINES")\]'$PS1
```

To prevent `tput` from changing the exit code, you can explicitly save and reset it:

```
PS1='\[$(retval=$?;tput cup "$LINES";exit $retval)\]'$PS1
```

Note that the variable `retval` is local; it doesn't affect any `retval` variable you might have defined otherwise in the shell.

Since most terminals `cup` capability is the same `\e[y;xH`, you could also hardcode it:

```
PS1='\[\e[$LINES;1H\]'$PS1
```

If you want it to be safe against later resetting of PS1, you can also utilize the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable. If set, it is run as command *before* the prompt is output. So the effect can also be achieved by

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='(retval=$?;tput cup "$LINES";exit $retval)'
```

Of course, while resetting `PS1` won't affect this, some other software might also change `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Comment: How `tput` differ from many `echo` commands ? (Asking out of curiosity)

Comment: @l0b0, probably doesn't deserve a separate answer. I hope celtschk won't mind I edited his/her answer.

Comment: `'\[$(tput cup "$LINES")\]'` [works beautifully](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/e2e15418c441ce8387f364bdeb9e153e3ad2695c). Thanks!

Comment: There is an issue with `tput`: It seems to reset `$exit_code`. [Fixed](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/67d3d32be636d2593b047f79042c75da14587b89) by using `\[\e[$LINES;1H\]`.

Comment: @l0b0: I've now added a version using `tput` that preserves the exit code.

Comment: This is not working when I put it in my .bashrc file... :/

Comment: @Relic: Maybe something else changes `PS1` later. I've now added another alternative independent of `PS1`.

Answer (score 4):

As a slight simplification to the previous answer, I found it easier to just run:

```
tput cup $LINES
```

in the beginning of `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`. It just does the job.

Pros:

- it only prints once, when you start your shell

Cons:

- when clearing screen with ^L, it doesn't print and aliasing `clear` to `clear; tput ...` doesn't help;
- prompt moves elsewhere when terminal is resized

Answer (score 4):

I have been using @Thomas Dickey's solution of including `\[\033[1000H\]` in `PS1` for a while and it has been frustrating me ever since as it breaks vi mode editing on multi-line commands, which is something that comes up quite often.

After investigating the problem several times over the past few months, I finally found a trivial change that prevents the issue: instead of including the ANSI escape sequence in `PS1`, it should be directly printed to `stdout` from `PROMPT_COMMAND` (in `~/.bashrc` or another configuration file):

```bash
PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt

prompt() {
    r="${?}"
    printf '\033[1000H'
    return "${r}"
}
```

`printf` and `return` are both builtins (see `builtins(1)`), so no processes are spawned. The exit status of the previous command is saved in `r`, cleared with `printf`, and restored with `return`. If `PROMPT_COMMAND` is already being used, this can simply be added to it.

This solution works with multi-line commands, but it has two minor limitations: first, clearing the screen with the `clear-screen` readline command (bound to `Control-L` by default) causes the prompt to go to the top of the screen, and second, increasing the size of a new terminal leaves the prompt where it was. In both cases, once the prompt is printed (e.g. by pressing enter) it goes back to the bottom of the screen (when bash runs `PROMPT_COMMAND`), which is an improvement over a single `tput cup 1000` or similar at the start of `~/.bashrc` as suggested by @phil pirozhkov.

Further investigation shows that the `clear` program works correctly because it prints terminal escape sequences directly (observable with `clear | xxd` or similar), which forces Bash to run `PROMPT_COMMAND` again. The `clear-screen` readline command, on the other hand, allows readline (used by Bash) to intercept the clear screen request and to simply re-display the previous prompt without rerunning `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Since the `\033[1000H` escape sequence is no longer in the prompt itself and rather is a side effect of running `PROMPT_COMMAND`, the prompt stays where it is.

The most general solution would be to patch Bash to run `PROMPT_COMMAND` when the terminal is resized or `clear-screen` is run. However, I opted for a more direct solution: patch the `clear-screen` command to print `\033[1000H` to `stdout` directly. For clarification, Bash's default source configuration includes its own copy of `readline`, but on my system (Gentoo Linux) the default Bash configuration is to use the system `readline`, and patching the system `readline` works for any other programs using it as well.

In any case, the simplest solution is to download Bash and apply the following patch with `patch -p1` in the Bash source directory:

```
--- a/lib/readline/display.c    2021-12-20 10:00:33.370809888 +0000
+++ b/lib/readline/display.c    2021-12-20 09:59:14.920808045 +0000
@@ -3186,11 +3186,17 @@
   ScreenClear ();
   ScreenSetCursor (0, 0);
 #else
+  static char const cup[]={'\033', '[', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'H'};
+  size_t i;
+
   if (_rl_term_clrpag)
     {
       tputs (_rl_term_clrpag, 1, _rl_output_character_function);
       if (clrscr && _rl_term_clrscroll)
    tputs (_rl_term_clrscroll, 1, _rl_output_character_function);
+
+      for (i=0; i < sizeof(cup); i++)
+   putc (cup[i], rl_outstream);
     }
   else
     rl_crlf ();
```

Note that this patch works for readline 8.1, included with Bash 5.1. The patch does not apply to readline 8.0 because it does not include the `clrscr` parameter to the `_rl_clear_screen` function, but changing the patch for this is straight forward.

While I was at it, I decided to make another improvement: instead of deleting the screen contents with the `clear-screen` command, I wanted to scroll the contents up so that I could access them later in my terminal's scroll back buffer. In order to achieve this, the following patch can be applied on top of the previous one:

```
--- a/lib/readline/display.c    2021-12-20 23:48:23.253322032 +0000
+++ b/lib/readline/display.c    2021-12-20 23:48:41.813321757 +0000
@@ -3191,6 +3191,15 @@
 
   if (_rl_term_clrpag)
     {
+      if (!clrscr)
+      {
+   for (i=0; i < sizeof(cup); i++)
+     putc (cup[i], rl_outstream);
+
+   for (i=0; i < _rl_screenheight; i++)
+     putc ('\n', rl_outstream);
+      }
+
       tputs (_rl_term_clrpag, 1, _rl_output_character_function);
       if (clrscr && _rl_term_clrscroll)
    tputs (_rl_term_clrscroll, 1, _rl_output_character_function);
```

With this the terminal and shell finally work exactly as I want them to. The only remaining problem is that increasing the size of the terminal before you have entered the first command leaves the prompt where it is, until you enter the first command. However, this is essentially a non-issue. I wrote both of the patches here and I hereby release them into the public domain under the CC0 Public Domain Disclosure (in case someone would like to incorporate them into future projects).

---

Edit: As requested by @Toby Speight, this can be adapted to other terminals. For `PROMPT_COMMAND`, simply save the output of `tput cup 1000` in a variable in `~/.bashrc` and print it instead of `\033[1000H`, as is done in [@Thomas Dickey's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/298822/507042).

For the patches, I directly embedded the `\033[1000H` escape sequence for speed (so as to only print one escape sequence to adjust the cursor position) and because only I was using it. A more portable solution is easily possible with the other readline functions in the same file ([`display.c`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/display.c?h=readline-8.1&id=cf3c762ecfff5b2f445647a0f1543693984a5540)), specifically the [`_rl_move_vert` function](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/display.c?h=readline-8.1&id=cf3c762ecfff5b2f445647a0f1543693984a5540#n2831). Unfortunately this is complicated by the fact that Bash/readline does not seem to accurately know its current vertical cursor position (stored in [`_rl_last_v_pos`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/display.c?h=readline-8.1&id=cf3c762ecfff5b2f445647a0f1543693984a5540#n201)) *in most cases*.

As far as I can tell the current cursor position is not queried upon startup, meaning it doesn't know where on the screen the prompt is starting. The `_rl_move_vert` function itself moves down with simply [`putc ('\n', rl_outstream)`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/display.c?h=readline-8.1&id=cf3c762ecfff5b2f445647a0f1543693984a5540#n2841), meaning that if it "moves down" when the cursor is already on the last line of the terminal it will actually scroll the terminal buffer.

The [`_rl_clear_screen` function](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/display.c?h=readline-8.1&id=cf3c762ecfff5b2f445647a0f1543693984a5540#n3183) also doesn't update `_rl_last_v_pos` at all, meaning it doesn't know where the cursor is after the screen is cleared with the `clear-screen` command, however this can be fixed (presumably) by setting it to zero in `_rl_clear_screen`. readline could presumably be extended to use escape sequences to move the cursor position, similar to its select use of `_rl_term_clrpag` (to clear the screen) and other related escape sequences. However, I'm unsure of how exactly this works and where these escape sequences are initialized.

In any case, I wrote a new patch using the `_rl_move_vert` function that still works. It's different from the previous patch in that the scroll back saving doesn't always scroll a full page, and instead only scrolls as much as it needs to (which may be desirable) -- at least, I think that's what it does:

```
--- a/lib/readline/display.c    2021-12-21 09:57:55.932774006 +0000
+++ b/lib/readline/display.c    2021-12-21 09:19:59.109474783 +0000
@@ -3186,11 +3186,25 @@
   ScreenClear ();
   ScreenSetCursor (0, 0);
 #else
+  int i;
+
   if (_rl_term_clrpag)
     {
+      if (!clrscr)
+      {
+   i = _rl_screenheight-_rl_last_v_pos;
+   _rl_move_vert(_rl_screenheight);
+
+   for (; i < _rl_screenheight; i++)
+     putc ('\n', rl_outstream);
+      }
+
       tputs (_rl_term_clrpag, 1, _rl_output_character_function);
       if (clrscr && _rl_term_clrscroll)
    tputs (_rl_term_clrscroll, 1, _rl_output_character_function);
+
+      _rl_last_v_pos = 0;
+      _rl_move_vert(_rl_screenheight);
     }
   else
     rl_crlf ();
```

Comment: Wow, fantastic work! Would you be willing to submit your patches to the readline project? I'd be super stoked to have this as an actual built-in feature, even if it ends up being behind a feature flag.

Comment: I'm all for it, but they would have to be configured by user options from `inputrc` since the default top terminal should remain, and that's more work than I'm interested in at the moment. As they are released into the public domain anyone is welcome to do so, however, or to send a link to this answer to their mailing list. For the time being, downloading Bash and applying the patches to its builtin readline is still easy enough even for people who aren't experienced with it. Anyways, thanks for the appreciation!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've suggested it to the [readline](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/readline/) maintainer directly, as I couldn't find any relevant mailing lists.

Comment: Can this be made so that it adapts properly to `$TERM`, rather than assuming the whole world is a VT-220 (or XTerm, or whatever)?  It's bloody irritating to get a screen filled with `^[` crap because someone assumed that all terminals are identical...

Comment: @TobySpeight At the risk of making an unnecessarily detailed answer even more unnecessarily detailed, I added a brand spanking new edit section hot off the shelves including a new version of the patch that will probably work for any terminal.

Answer (score 3):

The answers using `$LINES` are unnecessarily non-portable.  As done in [`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html), you can simply ask [`xterm`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/) to set the position to an arbitrarily large line number, e.g.,

```
tput cup 9999 0
```

(assuming that you have a window smaller than 10 thousand lines, disregarding *scrollback*).

Because the string will not change as a side-effect of resizing the window, you can compute this once, and paste it into your prompt-string as a constant, e.g.,

```
TPUT_END=$(tput cup 9999 0)
```

and later

```
PS1="${TPUT_END} myprompt: "
```

according to your preferences.

As for other processes modifying `PS1`: you will have to recompute `PS1` after those changes, to ensure that it looks as you want.  But there's not enough detail in the question to point out *where* to make the changes.

And finally: the behavior for tab-completion doesn't mesh with this sort of change, due to bash's assumptions.

Comment: What do you mean by "the behavior for tab-completion doesn't mesh with this sort of change"?

Comment: I think you mean `PS1="${TPUT_END} myprompt: "`, or even `PS1="${TPUT_END}${PS1}"`

Comment: For the latter - right (typo from thinking of makefiles).  For former, I have in mind that bash's command-editing relies on being able to reprint the line (with prompt), and that you can get some odd behavior when this combines with scrolling due to command-completion.